# How can I disable a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a button which is enabled at the beginning, but I want to disable it. I need it for a game. If the player chooses to play more, the game starts again, if not, the button "Click on me" should be disabled. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
    var y;
    function playAgain()
    {
        y=confirm("PLAY AGAIN?");

        if(y==true)
        {
            alert("Let's play it again!");
            location.reload(true);
        }
        else if(y==false)
        {
            alert("Thank you!\nSee you soon!");
            document.getElementById("button").disabled="disabled";
            //document.getElementById("button").disabled="true";
        }
    }
```

The HTML code:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click on me" onClick="playAgain()"  />
</body>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add `id="button"` to your input button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
```

If your button actually has `id="button"`:

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Click on me" onClick="playAgain()"  />
```

To re-enable the button set `.disabled = false;`

Answer (score 2):

You're using `document.getElementById("button")` but there is no element named `button` in the HTML.

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click on me" onClick="playAgain()"  />
```

Also, to disable a button, set its `disabled` attribute to true (false for otherwise).

```
document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can say

```
$("[type=button]").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    ... your other code ...
});
```

Comment: It's generally best to *not* drag in another library -- although this would work (because of the selector) -- as a primary fix. Take time to address why the current code doesn't work and then, if wanted, as *secondary* information, explain how it could be done using other means. Sometimes the other means are the correct way (although arguably not here), but always, always, focus/explain the primary issue in an answer and how the recommend approach fixes/addresses the problem.